# How to mock gorm insert with go-sql (postgres)

Tags: go, testing, go-gorm, go-sqlmock

I'm using [Gorm](https://gorm.io/) with the postgresql driver. I try to mock a database insert with [go-sqlmock](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock):

```
type Test struct {
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
}

func (db *DB) CreateTest() (*Test, error) {
    test := Test{"c"}
    if result := db.Create(&test); result.Error != nil {
        return nil, result.Error
    }

    return &test, nil
}


func TestCreateUser(t *testing.T) {
    _, mock, _ := sqlmock.NewWithDSN("sqlmock_db_0")

    mockedGorm, _ := gorm.Open("sqlmock", "sqlmock_db_0")
    defer mockedGorm.Close()
    myDB := &DB{mockedGorm}

    mock.ExpectExec("INSERT INTO test").WithArgs("c").WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))
    myDB.Exec("INSERT INTO test(first_name) VALUES (?)", "c")


    if _, err := myDB.CreateTest(); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("error was not expected: %s", err)
    }

    if err := mock.ExpectationsWereMet(); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("there were unfulfilled expectations: %s", err)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this gives me an error:

```
error was not expected: all expectations were already fulfilled, call to database transaction Begin was not expected
```

How do I test an insert with gorm, postgresql and sql-mock properly?

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit. "Begin was not expected". You didn't tell it to expect a Begin, which GORM is obviously executing.  What help do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a couple of issues with my code:

1) As @flimzy pointed out rightfully, there has to be a `ExpectBegin()` (and `ExpectCommit()`) statement. This gets more obvious if one turns on the GORM debugger that shows what exactly GORM is doing.

2) `ExpectExec("INSERT INTO test").WithArgs("c")` does quite obviously not match `myDB.Exec("INSERT INTO test(first_name) VALUES (?)", "c")`

3) One has to escape the statement, as go-sqlmock takes a regex, here Go's https://godoc.org/regexp#QuoteMeta comes in handy.

Working code:

```
mock.ExpectBegin()
mock.ExpectExec(regexp.QuoteMeta("INSERT INTO \"tests\" (\"first_name\") VALUES (?)")).WithArgs("c").WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))
mock.ExpectCommit()
```